# Как использовать обычные строки в f-строках?

Tags: python, строки

Как использовать обычные строки в f-строках?

У меня есть мапа с ключами-строками, хочу в f-строке получить какое-то значение из неё:

```
print(f'result = {data['result']}')
```

Comment: попробуйте так: `print(f"result = {map['result']}")`

Comment: @S.Nick а если мне по code style надо использовать только одиночные кавычки?

Comment: @дуля тогда не использовать обычные строки внутри f-строк. Можно вынести получение результата наружу, или использовать метод format вместо f-строки.

Comment: Для этого используют символ экранирования: `\ `(обратный слэш). Если поставить `\ ` перед кавычкой (одинарной или двойной), это скажет интерпретатору о том, что кавычку нужно рассматривать не как начало или конец строки, а как часть строки.

Comment: @S.Nick, в данном случае не сработает, показывает ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: @S.Nick@insolor можно пример кода?

Comment: @дуля, нафиг такой code style.

Comment: @Qwertiy это стандартный пункт -- использовать только 1 вид кавычек для строк, а не в одном месте одно, в другом -- другое

Comment: @дуля, это тоже подпадает под пункт `print(f'result = {data["result"]}')`? Странный стиль кода :) Я бы лучше ориентировался на гугловский: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'result': 'Hello World'}

print(f'result = {data["result"]}')
```

Просто используйте разные кавычки

Comment: вы смотрели первый комментарий ?

Comment: @S.Nick, а не надо в комментариях ответы писать. К тому же, у тебя кавычки наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
data = {'result': 'Hello World'}

 _f = data['result']

print(f'result = {_f}')  # result = Hello World
```

Comment: А без промежуточной переменной можно?

Comment: @дуля я вам показал различные варианты, примите решение о правильности моего ответа.

Comment: Подожду других ответов тогда, тут же только 1 ответ можно принять

Comment: @дуля удачи вам и терпения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `format` вместо f-строки:

```
print('result = {}'.format(data['result']))
```